# Memcached with Spring Boot

Tags: memcached, spring-boot

I have an application that uses spring-boot, and must work in parallel with other legacy application .

For this I'll use memcached for session storage, just that I can't find way to use the memcached in my application with spring-boot.

Someone please could tell me what I might add in the property file that corresponds to this change in context.xml

```
<Manager 
    className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"
    memcachedNodes="n1:servidor-memcached:11211"
    requestUriIgnorePattern=".*\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$"
/>
```

I'm using the Tomcat 7

Sorry for my english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring Boot doesn't provide any out-of-the-box support for using memcached for session storage so it cannot be configured via `application.properties`.

You can, however, configure it programatically by customising the embedded Tomcat instance. The following Java configuration is equivalent to the Tomcat `context.xml` in the question:

```java
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            MemcachedBackupSessionManager manager = new MemcachedBackupSessionManager();
            manager.setMemcachedNodes("n1:servidor-memcached:11211");
            manager.setRequestUriIgnorePattern(".*\\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$");
            context.setManager(manager);
        }

    };
}
```